# Hamburger menu button in tablayout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tablayout, hamburger-menu

I would like to know is there a way to integrate Hamburger menu button(Which toggles my NavigationView) into the TabLayout. As my ActionBar doesn't contain any action buttons except Hamburger menu button, I am thinking of removing ActionBar and integrating Hamburger menu button into the TabLayout. Can anyone help me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have a GoogleMap Fragmet in my Activity which fills the screen. It is hard to swipe for NavigationView without Hamburger menu button as the swiping is moving GoogleMap.

Comment: [Why and How to Avoid Hamburger Menus](https://lmjabreu.com/post/why-and-how-to-avoid-hamburger-menus/)

Comment: Sure, go ahead and do that.  You'll have to write all the code yourself or find some library to help you some aspect of it.  It's probably easier to just use the ActionBar even if you don't think you need it.